# Trouble using .is_integer() in python

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a python script that loops through a set of subdirectories I have and extracts a data file from each of those subdirectories. My subdirectories are each named for their corresponding time in a simulation I have fun earlier. However, the issue is that the integer subdirectories are listed without a decimal point (e.g. 5), while the non-integer subdirectories are listed with a decimal point. So in order to find the correct subdirectory, my loop is very sensitive to the number type.

With that, I have been trying to use the is._integer() method with python, but I keep getting this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'is_integer'
```

when I run the following code:

```
def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump

time=15

for i in frange(0,time,0.1):
    float(i)    
    print (i).is_integer()
```

even when I am brute forcing my loop variable to be a float! Please help.

Comment: and print(i.is_integer) , not print(i).is_integer

Answer (score 1):

Try `print(float(i).is_integer())`

The reason is that despite the fact that you casted `i` with `float(i)` before the usage of `(i).is_integer()`, it did not mutate the variable type of `i` to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

```
float(i)
```

This converts the argument `i` into a float, but that result is returned; it does not modify the variable `i`. So what that call does is simply discarded.

And in your case, in the first iteration, `i` is `0` which is an actual integer, and integer objects don’t have an `is_integer` method. So you either want to assign the restult of `float(i)` back to `i`:

```
for i in frange(0, time, 0.1):
    i = float(i)
    print (i).is_integer()
```

… or make sure that `frange` only returns floats:

```
def frange(x, y, jump):
    x = float(x)
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump
```

Comment: Ok, so all of these suggestions work (thank you!). However now I have made my code like this:
`Code'
    for i in frange(0,time,0.1):    
        x = float(i)    
        print x    
        print (x).is_integer()
`Code'
and the only value it is telling me I have an integer for is "0.0" and nothing else even though I am going up to a time of 15 with increments of 0.1. Thoughts?

Comment: That’s because it’s floating point arithmetic, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/216074).

Comment: But the reason I am using .is_integer() is because I thought it worked with floating point arithmetic

Comment: It works, but only if the number is exactly e.g. `1.00000000000000`. But that’s unlikey due to how floating point arithmetic works.

Comment: Hmmm... do you have any other suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: You could use module and then compare against some precision threshold, e.g. `i % 1 < 0.01` to check whether something is close to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not assign cast value to a variable. This should work:

```
def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump

time=15

for i in frange(0,time,0.1):
    x = float(i)    
    print (x).is_integer()
```

Comment: Ok, so all of these suggestions work (thank you!). However now I have made my code like this:
    for i in frange(0,time,0.1):    
        x = float(i)    
        print x    
        print (x).is_integer()
`Code'
and the only value it is telling me I have an integer for is "0.0" and nothing else even though I am going up to a time of 15 with increments of 0.1. Thoughts?